# Tableau Count distinct of count distinct

Tags: tableau-api

I have below data

```
Name    Product
XYZ A
XYZ B
XYZ A
MAP Z
MAP Z
```

I want only those customers that have more than 2 distinct products. So in the above example, we get only XYZ, so the count is 1.
Not sure how to do it.
Thanks,
Hema

Comment: You can use filter for this.

Comment: Actually, I need the number of customers with more than 1 product, not sure how filter will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to **see the customers without information on the different products**, you can drag the Name pill to rows, create a calculated field `distinct_products` as

```
COUNTD([Product])
```

and drag it to filter. Select 'at least' and enter '2'.

If you **still want to see the product information** you can solve this using [Level of Detail expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) in Tableau together with a filter.

Create a new calculated field `distinct_products` as follows:

```
{exclude [Product]: COUNTD([Product])}
```

Drag this to filters and choose attribute. Then select 'At Least' and enter '2' as value. Now the filter is in place. What you then need is to drag the 'Name' pill to rows.
If you want the products to be shown in a single row: drag the Product pill to 'Text'. If you want the products to appear in multiple rows, drag it to rows.

Comment: I dont want to see the customers. I want to know number of customers with total products (unique) >1

Comment: Sorry didnt see the last part.Thanks spijs, will check